# Java if else statement changing string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I have the following code but for some reason it won't change the string

The accountClass returns the string "L"

```
String accountClass = accClass.substring(4, 5);
        if (accountClass == "A") {
            accountClass = "Staff - A";
        } else if (accountClass == "B") {
            accountClass = "Student - B";
        } else if (accountClass == "H") {
            accountClass = "Personal - H";
        } else if (accountClass == "K") {
            accountClass = "60 Plus - K";
        } else if (accountClass == "L") {
            accountClass = "Business - L";
        } else if (accountClass == "P") {
            accountClass = "Charity - P";
        } else if (accountClass == "Q") {
            accountClass = "AIB Subsidiary - Q";
        } else if (accountClass == "X") {
            accountClass = "Irish State Spons & Sub's - X";
        } else if (accountClass == "Y") {
            accountClass = "Other Companies & Orgs - Y";
        } else if (accountClass == "Z") {
            accountClass = "Impersonal & Gen. Ledger - Z";
        }
```

I'm just wondering if its the == causing the problem or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check string equality with equals() method. In case of Objects `==` checks if two reference variables refer to the same instance. to check if two strings are meaningfully equal use `String.equals()` method.

```
if (accountClass == "A") {
```

should be

```
if (accountClass.equals("A")) {
```

and so does your other if statements.

Answer (score -1):

just realised it should be if (accountClass.equals("L"))

Comment: please upvote and accept the other answer that already told you this.

Comment: @Alnitak Actually, should read one of many thousands of the same answers to the same question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that too, including the one I wrote that has a hundred+ upvotes ;-)

Comment: thanks. yep srry I had googled but I was under time constraints. appreciated all help

Comment: @topcat3 if you are in a Java class, this should have been in one of the first sessions... I blame the teacher! ;-)

Comment: @PhiLho it probably was lol but sometimes you forget the easy bits when its staring you right in your face